# How to flip a page rectangular div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please, how do i flip a div element just as it was done here https://hyperiondev.com

Comment: @GentlemanMax i created a div with a paragraph in it, both have been given id. i've been searching for any hit online but they are not close to what I want.

Comment: Try looking at the source code of the page you want to mimic

Comment: Googling "Flip element with jQuery", first result [jQuery Flip](https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
https://jsfiddle.net/dhruv1992/m9xwg2ws/
HTML

```
    <div class="flip-container">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
      <span class="name">Dhruv Gupta</span>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <div class="back-logo"></div>
      <div class="back-title">Dhruv Gupta</div>
      <p>Javascript Fanatic, CSS Tinkerer, PHP Hacker, and web lover.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
    .flip-container {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -o-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;

    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

    .flip-container:hover .flipper,  
  .flip-container.hover .flipper {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 427px;
}

.flipper {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -moz-transition: 0.6s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

  -o-transition: 0.6s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

.front, .back {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.front {
    background: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f8/57/06/f85706c5f5e0b974a533ad6c8d1af258.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
    z-index: 2;
}

.back {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);

    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.front .name {
    font-size: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.9);
    color: #f8f8f8;
    font-family: Courier;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 25%;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #333;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
}

.back-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 90px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 117px;
    background: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f8/57/06/f85706c5f5e0b974a533ad6c8d1af258.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.back-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #00304a;
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0.05em #acd7e5;
    font-family: Courier;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.back p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
  font-family: arial;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I was under pressure.

Comment: no problem :) thanks